# C multi thread control with semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to learn about threads and semaphores.

I wish to write a code with 4 threads, which outputs a string like "foo dee", but I wish thread 1 to type only "f", 2 to type only "o", thread 3 to type only "e" and "d" and 4th thread to only type spaces.

How can I chain threads like to get a "foo dee" on the screen which is a mutual work of all of them.

I don't want a solution but an example of syntax I could work upon.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: working on linux

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to create semaphore structure and creating threads here : [for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx)
 and [for Linux](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=5)

What you need to do is: creating 4 threads inside main thread, and control them..

Hint: in windows WaitForMultipleObjects function makes the current thread wait.
ReleaseSemaphore function frees the semaphore and lets the other threads enter into critical section..

Example code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2]; sem_t mutex;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg) {
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    sem_wait(&mutex);         // Lock Entrance

    if(pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
    {
        printf("\n First thread processing\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Second thread processing\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++);

    sem_post(&mutex);         // Lock Exit

    return NULL; }

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int err;        if( sem_init(&mutex,1,1) < 0)
    {
      perror("semaphore initilization");
      exit(0);
    }

    while(i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

        i++;
    }

    sleep(5);
    return 0; }
```

Increase thread counter to get more threads..

Comment: Thanks but I went through that, maybe I failed to connect the dots. Could you possible give me and example?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to force threads to operate in sequence like this kind of defeats the purpose of creating the threads to begin with.  All of the other threads must wait on pre-defined behavior to occur.  To accomplish this goal, you have to block threads in a way that is not much different than operating sequentially (and then on top of this, you add the overhead of the thread creation and management)

... but if you really want to do this, I'd use signals instead of semaphors.  Semaphors and mutexes are generally used to control concurrent access to a shared resource.  By forcing execution order, there really is no shared resource to speak of.

The idea behind the signals is that one thread will wait until another thread kicks it into gear.  Take a look at the following functions:

```
pthread_cond_wait()
pthread_cond_signal()
```

I think that they're the best way to get you what you want.